# I can't do local firebase imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

To do the imports I have to do them with the https route:`import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-app.js";`since it does not let me import them in this way:`import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";`Although in the project I have installed firebase with this command:`npm install firebase`. I tryed in windows with another nodejs installation and the result is the same.

this is the config file:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

        import {
          getFirestore,
          collection,
          getDocs,
          onSnapshot,
          addDoc,
          deleteDoc,
          doc,
          getDoc,
          updateDoc,
        } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-firestore.js";

import { 
  getAuth, 
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword, 
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut
} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-auth.js';     

const firebaseConfig = {
//mydata

};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

and this is the app.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {auth,db} from './firebase';

import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  onSnapshot,
  addDoc,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  getDoc,
  updateDoc
}from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-firestore.js";


import { 
  getAuth, 
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword, 
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut
} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.1/firebase-auth.js';  


  function App() {

    const [tareas, setTareas] = React.useState([])
    const [tarea, setTarea] = React.useState('')
    const [modoEdicion, setModoEdicion] = React.useState(false)
    const [id, setId] = React.useState('')
    const [categorias, setCategorias] = React.useState([])
    const [categoria, setCategoria] = React.useState([])

    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('prueba@prueba.com')
    const [pass, setPass] = React.useState('123123')
    const [error, setError] = React.useState(null)
    const [esRegistro, setEsRegistro] = React.useState(false)
  
  React.useEffect(() => {

    const obtenerDatos = async () => {

      try {
        
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db,"Articulos"));
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       
        });
        
        const arrayData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id,titulo:doc.data().titulo ,contenido:doc.data().contenido}))
        setTareas(arrayData)
      
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)}
    }
  
    const obtenerCategorias = async () => {

      try {


        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db,"Categorias"));
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       
        });
        const arrayData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id,nombre:doc.data().nombre}))
        setCategorias(arrayData)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
      
    }

    obtenerDatos()
    obtenerCategorias()

  }, [])

  const agregar = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if(!tarea.trim()){
      console.log('está vacio')
      return
    }

    try {

      const nuevaTarea = {
        titulo: "tarea",
        contenido: "categoria"
      }
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db,"Articulos"), {titulo:tarea,contenido:categoria});

      setTareas([
        ...tareas,
        {titulo:tarea,contenido:categoria, id: docRef.id}

      ])

      setTarea('')
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }


  }

  const eliminar = async (id) => {
    try {
      

      const articleToDelete = doc(db,`Articulos/${id}`)
      db.deleteDoc(articleToDelete)

      const arrayFiltrado = tareas.filter(item => item.id !== id)
      setTareas(arrayFiltrado)

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  const activarEdicion = (item) => {
    setModoEdicion(true)
    setTarea(item.name)
    setId(item.id)
  }

  const handleUpdate = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const taskDocRef = doc(db, 'Articulos', id)
    try{
      await updateDoc(taskDocRef, {
        titulo: tarea,
        contenido: categoria
      })
    
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db,"Articulos"));
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          
       
        });
        const arrayData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id,titulo:doc.data().titulo ,contenido:doc.data().contenido}))
        setTareas(arrayData)

      setModoEdicion(false)
      setTarea('')
      setId('')

    } catch (err) {
      alert(err)
    }    
  }
  //const Login = (props) => {



    const procesarDatos = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if(!email.trim() || !pass.trim()){
            console.log('Datos vacíos email!')
            setError('Datos vacíos email!')
            return
        }
        if(!pass.trim()){
            console.log('Datos vacíos pass!')
            setError('Datos vacíos pass!')
            return
        }
        if(pass.length < 6){
            console.log('6 o más carácteres')
            setError('6 o más carácteres en pass')
            return
        }
        console.log('correcto...')
        setError(null)

        if(esRegistro){
            registrar()
        }else{
            login()
        }

    }

    //const login = React.useCallback(async () => {
      function login(){
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pass)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user)
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
      });
    //}, [email, pass, props.history])
    //}, [])
      }

      function registrar(){
    //const registrar = React.useCallback(async() => {

      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, pass)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // ..
      });

    //}, [email, pass, props.history])
    //}, [])
      }
  //}
  
  //const CuadroTexto = ({ titulo }) => <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value={titulo}/>

  function cerrar(){
    signOut(auth).then(() => {
      console.log("deslogeado")
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("error")
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="container mt-3">
      <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6">
          <h3>Lista de tareas</h3>
          <table border="1">

            {
              tareas.map(item => (
                
                  <tr>
                    
                  <td>{item.titulo}</td>
                  <td>{item.contenido}</td>
                  <td>
                  <button 
                    className="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right"
                    onClick={() => eliminar(item.id)}
                  >                
                    Eliminar
                  </button>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  <button 
                    className="btn btn-warning btn-sm float-right mr-2"
                    onClick={() => activarEdicion(item)}
                  >
                    Editar
                  </button>
                  </td>
                
                  </tr>
                
              ))
            }

          </table>
        </div>
        
        
<div className="col-md-6">
          <h3>
            {
              modoEdicion ? 'Editar Tarea' : 'Agregar Tarea'
            }
          </h3>
          <form onSubmit={modoEdicion ? handleUpdate : agregar}>
            <input 
              type="text"
              placeholder="Ingrese tarea"
              className="form-control mb-2"
              onChange={e => setTarea(e.target.value)}
              value={tarea}
            />
            <select 
            onChange={c => setCategoria(c.target.value)} value={categoria}>
                    {
                     
                    categorias.map(item2 => (
                    <option 
                    value={item2.nombre}
                    >
                      {item2.nombre}
                      </option>
                    ))
                    }
            </select>
            <button 
              className={
                modoEdicion ? 'btn btn-warning btn-block' : 'btn btn-dark btn-block'
              }
              type="submit"
            >
              {
                modoEdicion ? 'Editar' : 'Agregar'
              }
            </button>
            
          </form>
        </div> 
        
        <h3 className="text-center">
                {
                    esRegistro ? 'Registro' : 'Login'
                }
            </h3>
            <hr/>
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-xl-4">
                    <form onSubmit={procesarDatos}>
                        {
                            error ? (
                                <div className="alert alert-danger">
                                    {error}
                                </div>
                            ) : null
                        }
                        <input 
                            type="email" 
                            className="form-control mb-2"
                            placeholder="Ingrese Email"
                            onChange={ e => setEmail(e.target.value) }
                            value={email}
                        />
                        <input 
                            type="password" 
                            className="form-control mb-2"
                            placeholder="Ingrese Contraseña"
                            onChange={ e => setPass(e.target.value) }
                            value={pass}
                        />
                        <button 
                            className="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-block"
                            type="submit"
                        >
                            {esRegistro ? 'Registrar' : 'Acceder'}
                        </button>
                        <button 
                            className="btn btn-lg btn-dark btn-block"
                            type="button"
                            onClick={() => cerrar()}
                        >
                            Logout
                        </button>
                        <button 
                            className="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-block"
                            type="button"
                            onClick={() => setEsRegistro(!esRegistro)}
                        >
                            {esRegistro ? '¿Ya tienes cuenta?' : '¿No tienes cuenta?'}
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is the error that shows the console:`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Component auth has not been registered yet`
Greetings

Comment: Try doing `import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"` and then acces it as `firebase.initializeApp`.

Comment: it did not worked. (i'm using 9.8.1 version)

Answer (score 2):

**Try import firebase this way**

```
import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

if (!getApps().length) {
  initializeApp(JSON.parse(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT));
}

const firestore = getFirestore();
const auth = getAuth();

export { firestore, auth };
```

and my env looks like this

```js
  NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    measurementId: "",
  };
```

I'm using firebase version 9.6.5

Comment: it launch me this error: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: I also tried it from windows, with another installation of nodejs and different reacts but the result is the same, with which it is either from my code or from the new version of firebase.

Comment: and i also tryed with your firebase version (9.6.5) and the result is the same. It have to be from my code. I edited the first post and i have added the entire app.js file.

Comment: is your repo public, so you share a link to it

Comment: yes my repo is public, you can acess it here: https://github.com/palanganero/reactfirebase
To be able to see the data you must log in with this username and password: user: natalia.guillan@gmail.com password:1234567   and refresh

Comment: everything would be fine doing the imports with https, but the problem is that it doesn't let me build the project that way

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Github repo](https://github.com/Chukwu3meka/Firebase-Auth)

```
"firebase": "^9.6.8"
"firebase-admin": "^10.0.2"
```

It should work for latest version too

Comment: Thanks but keeps without working.